# Storing an Array of String to a Key in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, mongodb, backend

I'm building a post request which will contain various info on each role. E.g in this trial, 'Data Analyst'.

In this position I want to have quite a few sources of data, including things like salary, education and skills.
However, I'm using recharts to visualise it, which means although I need a key, e.g Masters's degree, I also need a num value associated, such as below:

```
const educationData = [
  {
    degree: 'Masters',
    A: 120,

  },
  {
    degree: 'Bachelor',
    A: 98,
  },
  {
    degree: 'PhD',
    A: 86,
  },
  {
    degree: 'Industry',
    A: 99,
  },
  {
    degree: 'Associate',
    A: 85,
  }
];
```

I would like to store this inside my schema created:

```
const RolesPositionSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        title:{type:String, required: true, unique: true},
        desc:{type:String, required: true},
        skills:{type:Array, required: true},
        salary:{type:Array}, 
        education: {type: Array},
        popularity: {type: Number},
        reccomendations: {type: Array},
    },
);
```

Within this I would like to store the 'educationData' into the DB. Happy to input it in manually for now. I just want to know how to structure my schema/data in the postman request.

E.g Input in "education", stored with "Masters:120", "Bachelor:98", "PhD:86" etc -> within the post request:

```
{
    "title" : "Data Analyst",
    "desc": "Using both internal and external data sources you will develop insights to identify trends and opportunities whilst highlighting areas or improvement to optimise member interaction. This is a proactive role where you will own how we interpret data, allowing you to   provide valuable insight into the development and implementation of product, customer and channel strategies for our sales, retention, and acquisition goals.",
    "skills":["SQL" ,"Excel", "Tableau", "PowerBI", "Python", "Azure", "AWS", "ETL"],
    "education": ["INPUT AN ARRAY OF EDUCATION AND THEIR VALUES HERE!]
}
```

Thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

You could modify first your payload into the format of schema.

**Payload**

```
const educationData = [
  {
    degree: 'Masters',
    A: 120,
  },
  {
    degree: 'Bachelor',
    A: 98,
  },
  {
    degree: 'PhD',
    A: 86,
  },
  {
    degree: 'Industry',
    A: 99,
  },
  {
    degree: 'Associate',
    A: 85,
  }
];
```

**Process**

```
const newEducations = educationData.map(education => {
    return `${education.degree}:${education.A}`;
});

const storeRole = new RolesPositionSchema({
    title: 'Data Analyst',
    desc: 'Using both internal and external data sources you will develop insights to identify trends and opportunities whilst highlighting areas or improvement to optimise member interaction. This is a proactive role where you will own how we interpret data, allowing you to   provide valuable insight into the development and implementation of product, customer and channel strategies for our sales, retention, and acquisition goals.',
    skills: [{Skill value}],
    salary: [{Salary value}],
    education: newEducations,
    popularity: 0,
    reccomendations: [{Recommendation value}]
});
```

After this saved.
Does it that you want?